# How to add vertical space between sequence diagram calls?

Tags: pgf-umlsd, shortstack

I am using the package `pgf-umlsd` to draw a sequence diagram. I have two subsequent calls nested inside a parent call. When I use `\shortstack` to write the label of the second call, there is an overlapping with the previous call.

[image]

This is my source code:

```
\begin{sequencediagram}
    \renewcommand\unitfactor{0.7}
    \tikzstyle{inststyle}+=[minimum width=2cm, minimum height=1cm, rounded corners=3mm]
    
    \newthread{user}{User}
    \newinst[1]{client}{Client}
    \newinst[1]{inst1}{inst1}
    \newinst[1]{inst2}{inst2}
    
    \begin{call}{user}{Authenticate}{client}{Home page}
    
        \begin{call}[2]{client}{call1()}{inst1}{return}
        \end{call}
        
        \begin{call}[3]
        {client}{\shortstack{\texttt{POST /token} \\ Client ID + Client}}{inst2}{access token}
        \end{call}
    
    \end{call}

\end{sequencediagram}
```

How can I create more space vertically between consecutive calls?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the solution, posting here to help others.
Just add the `\postlevel` command between subsequent calls.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{pgf-umlsd}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{sequencediagram}
    \renewcommand\unitfactor{0.7}
    \tikzstyle{inststyle}+=[minimum width=2cm, minimum height=1cm, rounded corners=3mm]
    
    \newthread{user}{User}
    \newinst[1]{client}{Client}
    \newinst[1]{inst1}{inst1}
    \newinst[1]{inst2}{inst2}
    
    \begin{call}{user}{Authenticate}{client}{Home page}
    
        \begin{call}[2]{client}{call1()}{inst1}{return}
        \end{call}

        \postlevel
        
        \begin{call}[3]
        {client}{\shortstack{\texttt{POST /token} \\ Client ID + Client}}{inst2}{access token}
        \end{call}
    
    \end{call}

\end{sequencediagram}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Nice answer, could you improve it by making it compile please? As in, could you include a `\documentclass{}`, necessary packages and commands so that future people can try your code straight away please :)